# Why didn't the White queen take the Black rook here?

Tags: rooks, queens

I was seeing [this match on chess.com](https://www.chess.com/daily/game/202123292).

```
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "18"]

1. e4 e5
2. Nf3 Nc6
3. Bc4 h6
4. O-O d6
5. d3 Bg4
6. c3 a6
7. Nbd2 Nf6
8. Qb3 Qe7
9. Qxb7 Nd8
10. Qb3 Be6
11. Qa4+ Bd7
12. Qc2 g6
13. Nb3 Bg7
14. d4
```

The White queen had a chance to take the Black rook, but the White queen came back, why?

Comment: The game is still ongoing. Do you have consent of both players to publically ask analyzing questions about it? Otherwise, this might be considered illegal assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's just a blunder from White; the white queen is not at risk of being trapped, nor is it needed for defense. Qxa8 would have definitely been the best move.

Note that the player's ratings aren't that high (no idea how they compare to FIDE ratings though).

Comment: Amazing, considering it is a correspondence game at three days per move. I often play in that rating range and people usually don't miss that kind of move.

Comment: @itub There are lots of people that play online correspondence much like they play blitz, sadly. I have seen some that had something like 100 correspondence games open at the same time, and subsequently only spent less than a minute per single move.

Comment: @Annatar good point! I usually have only two or three games at a time. :-)